# insync messed up apt and I can't do apt-get update/upgrade

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, aptitude

I had issues with 1.2.x version of `insync`, so I googled for its website and I downloaded the *deb* file of the newest version for my 64 bit debian. `dpkg` couldn't install it, even setting the `--force-all` option, the output is

```
   ale@debian:~/Scaricati$ sudo dpkg --force-all -i insync_1.3.12.36116-wheezy_amd64.deb 
   [sudo] password for ale:          
   (Reading database ... 342721 files and directories currently installed.)
   Preparing to unpack insync_1.3.12.36116-wheezy_amd64.deb ...
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
   zipimport.ZipImportError: not a Zip file: '/usr/lib/insync/library.zip'
   dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
   dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
   zipimport.ZipImportError: not a Zip file: '/usr/lib/insync/library.zip'
   dpkg: error processing archive insync_1.3.12.36116-wheezy_amd64.deb (--install):
    subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
   zipimport.ZipImportError: not a Zip file: '/usr/lib/insync/library.zip'
   *** Error in `dpkg': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x000055edcb3d9751 ***
   ======= Backtrace: =========
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3d93a70bcb)[0x7f34a30b2bcb]
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3d93a76fa6)[0x7f34a30b8fa6]
   dpkg(+0x20060)[0x55edc8b7c060]
   dpkg(+0x204b9)[0x55edc8b7c4b9]
   dpkg(+0x277fa)[0x55edc8b837fa]
   dpkg(+0x16b07)[0x55edc8b72b07]
   dpkg(+0x16ce5)[0x55edc8b72ce5]
   dpkg(+0x16f2d)[0x55edc8b72f2d]
   dpkg(+0xa297)[0x55edc8b66297]
   dpkg(+0x1ff9b)[0x55edc8b7bf9b]
   dpkg(+0x201a1)[0x55edc8b7c1a1]
   dpkg(+0x9d22)[0x55edc8b65d22]
   dpkg(+0x66a9)[0x55edc8b626a9]
   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f34a30622b1]
   dpkg(+0x67e9)[0x55edc8b627e9]
   ======= Memory map: ========
   55edc8b5c000-55edc8ba0000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5505633                    /usr/bin/dpkg
   55edc8da0000-55edc8da3000 r--p 00044000 08:06 5505633                    /usr/bin/dpkg
   55edc8da3000-55edc8da4000 rw-p 00047000 08:06 5505633                    /usr/bin/dpkg
   55edc8da4000-55edc8fb8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   55edcac76000-55edceccb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
   7f34a1bff000-7f34a1c15000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5637055                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
   7f34a1c15000-7f34a1e14000 ---p 00016000 08:06 5637055                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
   7f34a1e14000-7f34a1e15000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 5637055                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
   7f34a1e15000-7f34a2170000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f34a2170000-7f34a217a000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5637413                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
   7f34a217a000-7f34a237a000 ---p 0000a000 08:06 5637413                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
   7f34a237a000-7f34a237b000 r--p 0000a000 08:06 5637413                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
   7f34a237b000-7f34a237c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:06 5637413                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.24.so
   7f34a237c000-7f34a2382000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f34a2382000-7f34a238d000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5637477                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.24.so
   7f34a238d000-7f34a258c000 ---p 0000b000 08:06 5637477                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.24.so
   7f34a258c000-7f34a258d000 r--p 0000a000 08:06 5637477                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.24.so
   7f34a258d000-7f34a258e000 rw-p 0000b000 08:06 5637477                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.24.so
   7f34a258e000-7f34a25a2000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5639731                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.24.so
   7f34a25a2000-7f34a27a2000 ---p 00014000 08:06 5639731                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.24.so
   7f34a27a2000-7f34a27a3000 r--p 00014000 08:06 5639731                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.24.so
   7f34a27a3000-7f34a27a4000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 5639731                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.24.so
   7f34a27a4000-7f34a27a6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f34a27a6000-7f34a27ad000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5637380                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.24.so
   7f34a27ad000-7f34a29ac000 ---p 00007000 08:06 5637380                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.24.so
   7f34a29ac000-7f34a29ad000 r--p 00006000 08:06 5637380                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.24.so
   7f34a29ad000-7f34a29ae000 rw-p 00007000 08:06 5637380                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.24.so
   7f34a29ae000-7f34a29c6000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5636302                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
   7f34a29c6000-7f34a2bc5000 ---p 00018000 08:06 5636302                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
   7f34a2bc5000-7f34a2bc6000 r--p 00017000 08:06 5636302                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
   7f34a2bc6000-7f34a2bc7000 rw-p 00018000 08:06 5636302                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
   7f34a2bc7000-7f34a2bcb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f34a2bcb000-7f34a2bcd000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5636507                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
   7f34a2bcd000-7f34a2dcd000 ---p 00002000 08:06 5636507                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
   7f34a2dcd000-7f34a2dce000 r--p 00002000 08:06 5636507                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
   7f34a2dce000-7f34a2dcf000 rw-p 00003000 08:06 5636507                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
   7f34a2dcf000-7f34a2e41000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5636499                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3
   7f34a2e41000-7f34a3040000 ---p 00072000 08:06 5636499                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3
   7f34a3040000-7f34a3041000 r--p 00071000 08:06 5636499                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3
   7f34a3041000-7f34a3042000 rw-p 00072000 08:06 5636499                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3
   7f34a3042000-7f34a31d7000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5636270                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
   7f34a31d7000-7f34a33d6000 ---p 00195000 08:06 5636270                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
   7f34a33d6000-7f34a33da000 r--p 00194000 08:06 5636270                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
   7f34a33da000-7f34a33dc000 rw-p 00198000 08:06 5636270                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
   7f34a33dc000-7f34a33e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f34a33e0000-7f34a3404000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5636565                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
   7f34a3404000-7f34a3603000 ---p 00024000 08:06 5636565                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
   7f34a3603000-7f34a3604000 r--p 00023000 08:06 5636565                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
   7f34a3604000-7f34a3605000 rw-p 00024000 08:06 5636565                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
   7f34a3605000-7f34a3607000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f34a3607000-7f34a362a000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 5636259                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
   7f34a3662000-7f34a37fb000 r--p 00000000 08:06 5505564                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
   7f34a37fb000-7f34a37fd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f34a3825000-7f34a3829000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7f34a3829000-7f34a382a000 r--p 00022000 08:06 5636259                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
   7f34a382a000-7f34a382b000 rw-p 00023000 08:06 5636259                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
   7f34a382b000-7f34a382c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
   7fffe1f34000-7fffe1f55000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
   7fffe1f9e000-7fffe1fa0000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
   7fffe1fa0000-7fffe1fa2000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
   ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
   Aborted
```

So I said *"who cares about insync, nautilus has google drive integration"*, so I decided to uninstall `insync` but I couldn't. Now, magically, I cannot run anymore `apt-get upgrade` or `aptitude upgrade`, I get this error output:

```
   Resolving dependencies...               
   The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  insync
   No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
   0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
   E: Can't find a source to download version '1.3.10.36104-wheezy' of 'insync:amd64'
   After unpacking 0 B will be used.
   E: Can't find a source to download version '1.3.10.36104-wheezy' of 'insync:amd64'
   E: Internal error: couldn't generate list of packages to download
   E: Perhaps the package lists are out of date, please try 'aptitude update' (or equivalent) first
```

This maybe because the `insync` repo is unaccessable (which is, for the record, [this one](http://deb%20http://apt.insynchq.com/ubuntu%20precise%20non-free%20contrib)).

What's more, I can't even open `synaptic` without getting this nice error:

```
   An error occurred
   the following details are prodived
   E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
   E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

of course insync is the cause of all this:

```
   ale@debian:~/Scaricati$ sudo dpkg --audit && echo ok
   The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
   installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
   that depend on them) to function properly:
    insync               Google Drive sync and backup with multiple    account suppor
```

What can I do, what can be done to solve this hideous situation and have my daily package upgrade back? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Did you run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: of course I did. The output is `ale@debian:~/Scaricati$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error processing package insync (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 insync`

Comment: How about *purge*: `dpkg -P insync`?

Comment: the same `ale@debian:~/Scaricati$ sudo dpkg -P insync
dpkg: error processing package insync (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 insync`

Comment: Based on *Ipugoy*'s comment on [this thread](https://forums.insynchq.com/t/insync-not-starting/1832/15) try running this `mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/insync.prerm ~/insync.prerm.bak`, and *then* purge or remove as before.

Comment: I solved in another way I found online: I removed insync entry in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`, did `apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` again and everything started working fine back

Comment: please post that as an answer, and mark this Q solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in another way I found online: I removed insync entry in

```
   /var/lib/dpkg/status,
```

did

```
   apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

again and everything started working fine back